# Java.persistance.rollback.rollback exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am facing jdbc connection exception issue showing unable to acquire jdbc connection and after referring below link I changed by class instead of creating each method entitymsnager instance I replaced with single entitymangar with persistencecontext annotation and type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED.

[Spring with Hibernate JPA - EntityManager is closed exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875366/spring-with-hibernate-jpa-entitymanager-is-closed-exception/64551184#64551184)

But  after adding
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager entityManager;

That issue resolved ,but now when multiple users access at the same time throwing Java.persistance.rollbackbexception error while committing transaction

Please find below code uses EntityManger in my application

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Transactional
@Service
public class QueryService implements IQueryService {

  @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
  private EntityManager em;

  @Override
  public List<XXXXXX> getXXXXXJPQLQuery(String XXXX) {

    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM XXX ca,XXX c  "
      + "WHERE ca.XXX = :XXX AND " + "ca.XXX = c.XX");

    query.setParameter("XXX", XX);
    List<CustInfoReqRes> list = (List<XXX>) query.getResultList();
    return list;
  }

 
  @Override
  public List<XXX> getXXXXNoJPQLQuery(String XX, String XX, String XX) {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT ca FROM XXX a,XX ca "
      + " WHERE a.XXX=:XX AND a.XXX = :XX "
      + "AND a.XXX = :XXX AND " + "a.XXX= ca.XXX");

    query.setParameter("XX", XX);
    query.setParameter("XX", XX);
    query.setParameter("XX", XX);
    List<XX> list = (List<XX>) query.getResultList();
    return list;
  }

}
`
```

ErrMsg Error while committing the transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the tran. jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor278.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at com.library.web.filters.Webfilter.doFilter(Webfilter.java:74) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at com.library.logging.AppRequsetFilter.doFilterWrapped(AppRequsetFilter.java:79) at com.library.logging.AppRequsetFilter.doFilterInternal(AppRequsetFilter.java:55) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error while committing the transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:408) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerSynchronization.convertException(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:511) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerSynchronization.afterCommit(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:484) at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:134) at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:122) at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:945) at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:782) at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:632) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) at com.xxxx.QueryService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3d67e376.getxxxxxNoJPQLQuery() at com.:76) ... 59 more Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81) at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerSynchronization.afterCommit(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:481) ... 72 more Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154) at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:65) ... 74 more Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1356) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:451) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3210) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2378) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447) at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ... 73 more

Comment: How do you expect us to help with the few details you've provided? What's the stacktrace you get? How are you making sure each user gets their own entitymanager?

Comment: Hi Thomas I have updated my post ,added stack trace ,And am not sure how to provide each user gets its own enittymanager,As per my understanding after using this @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED) annotation framewrk vl handle this,Plz help as am wrking in this situation for the first time

Comment: Please reformat the stack trace and post it as a code block. Add proper line breaks, i.e. it should look similar to what it looks like in the log file or on the command line.