# Integration tests sometimes throw "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Data source context must be initialized"

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, integration-testing, embedded-database

It seems to happen randomly when running integration tests that need docker.
Happens only on Windows.

stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Data source context must be initialized
    at io.zonky.test.db.shaded.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:459) ~[embedded-database-spring-test-2.1.1.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.context.DefaultDatabaseContext.reset(DefaultDatabaseContext.java:190) ~[embedded-database-spring-test-2.1.1.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.lambda$resetDatabases$0(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:59) ~[embedded-database-spring-test-2.1.1.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.lambda$forEachDatabase$5(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:98) ~[embedded-database-spring-test-2.1.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[na:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.forEachDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:96) ~[embedded-database-spring-test-2.1.1.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.resetDatabases(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:58) ~[embedded-database-spring-test-2.1.1.jar:na]
    at io.zonky.test.db.EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.beforeTestClass(EmbeddedDatabaseTestExecutionListener.java:34) ~[embedded-database-spring-test-2.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestClass(TestContextManager.java:213) ~[spring-test-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60) ~[spring-test-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) ~[spring-test-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306) ~[junit-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413) ~[junit-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) ~[junit-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) ~[junit-4.13.1.jar:4.13.1]
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:43) ~[junit-vintage-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:82) ~[junit-vintage-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:73) ~[junit-vintage-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]


Test ignored.
```

integration test class which fails:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@Import({FirebaseServerMock.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureEmbeddedDatabase
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = FirebaseConnectorService.class),
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = UserEntity.class),
})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "scheduler.defaultMinimumPreOrderTime=-999990",
    "scheduler.vehicleCheckDurationMinutes=15",
    "scheduler.immutability.minutesBeforeTripDeparture=2000", // more than 24h
    "scheduler.breakSchedulingMarginMinutes=10"
})
public class PicturesUploadForDriverIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    FirebaseServerMock firebaseServerMock;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    DriverRepository driverRepository;

    @Autowired
    FileRepository fileRepository;

    @Autowired
    DriverFileRepository driverFileRepository;

    @Autowired
    ScheduledFileTasks scheduledFileTasks;

    @Value("classpath:other/id_card_1.jpg")
    private Resource file1;

    @Value("classpath:other/id_card_2.jpg")
    private Resource file2;

    final UUID DRIVER = UUID.fromString("d333d333-ea5f-4d89-8d72-e6eb63bb3b83"); // from sql
    final UUID DRIVER_USER = UUID.fromString("d444d444-ea5f-4d89-8d72-e6eb63bb3b84"); // from sql
    final UUID DISTRIBUTOR_USER = UUID.fromString("d444d444-ea5f-4d89-8d72-e6eb63bb3b83"); // from sql

    MockMultipartFile fileMock1, fileMock2;

    @Test
    @Sql("/fixtures/picturesUploadForDriver.sql")
    @FlywayTest
    @Transactional
    public void uploadPicturesTest() throws Exception {
        // prepare object mapper
        AccessToken driverToken = firebaseServerMock.mockVerifiableToken(userRepository.findByUuid(DRIVER_USER).orElse(null).getFirebaseUid());
        AccessToken distributorToken = firebaseServerMock.mockVerifiableToken(userRepository.findByUuid(DISTRIBUTOR_USER).orElse(null).getFirebaseUid());

        /*
         * 1) as driver, I open the driver app (whoAmI context is asked) and I become information, that I need upload driver licence pictures
         */
        MvcResult resultDriverWhoAmI1 = mockMvc.perform(
                get("/api/whoami")
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + driverToken.getValue())
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

        String whoAmI1Json = resultDriverWhoAmI1.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.isDriverLicenceCheckNeeded", equalTo(true))); // file(s) upload must be done
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.userId", equalTo(DRIVER_USER.toString())));
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.email", equalTo("driver@fubar.com")));
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.name", equalTo("Patra, Cleo")));
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.phone", equalTo("0987654321")));
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.dateOfBirth", equalTo(null)));
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.address.streetNumber", equalTo(null)));
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.address.zipCode", equalTo(null)));
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.address.city", equalTo(null)));
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.address.country", equalTo(null)));
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.pleaseComplete", equalTo(false)));
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.isStripeCustomerConnected", equalTo(false)));
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.hasDefaultStripePaymentMethod", equalTo(false)));
        assertThat(whoAmI1Json, hasJsonPath("$.privileges.[*]", hasSize(11)));

        /*
         * 2) as driver, I use the driver app to upload 2 files
         */
        // prepare file mocks
        fileMock1 = new MockMultipartFile(
            "file",
            "id_card_1.jpg",
            MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,
            file1.getInputStream()
        );
        fileMock2 = new MockMultipartFile(
            "file",
            "id_card_2.jpg",
            MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,
            file2.getInputStream()
        );
        MvcResult resultDriverFile1Upload = mockMvc.perform(
                multipart("/api/files/driver-licence/upload")
                    .file(fileMock1)
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + driverToken.getValue())
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

        String resultDriverFile1Json = resultDriverFile1Upload.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertThat(resultDriverFile1Json, hasJsonPath("$.name", equalTo("id_card_1.jpg")));
        String fileId1 = JsonPath.read(resultDriverFile1Json, "$.fileId");

        MvcResult resultDriverFile2Upload = mockMvc.perform(
                multipart("/api/files/driver-licence/upload")
                    .file(fileMock2)
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + driverToken.getValue())
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

        String resultDriverFile2Json = resultDriverFile2Upload.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertThat(resultDriverFile2Json, hasJsonPath("$.name", equalTo("id_card_2.jpg")));
        String fileId2 = JsonPath.read(resultDriverFile2Json, "$.fileId");

        // check, whether files saved in db
        assertTrue(fileRepository.findByUuid(UUID.fromString(fileId1)).isPresent());
        assertTrue(fileRepository.findByUuid(UUID.fromString(fileId2)).isPresent());

        /*
         * 3) as driver, I use the driver app to assign uploaded files to me
         */
        String sendFilesBody = "{\n" +
            "\"fileIds\": [\"" + fileId1 + "\",\"" + fileId2 + "\"],\n" +
            "\"fileType\": \"DRIVER_LICENSE\"\n" +
            "}";
        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/api/command/saveDriverFiles")
                    .content(sendFilesBody)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + driverToken.getValue())
            );

        // check driver data
        DriverEntity driver = driverRepository.findByUuid(DRIVER).orElseThrow();
        assertEquals(LocalDate.now(), driver.getLastCheckDriverLicence());
        assertEquals((Integer) 30, driver.getNextCheckDriverLicenceIn());
        assertEquals(2, driver.getDriverFiles(DRIVER_LICENSE).size());
        assertTrue(driver.getDriverFiles(DRIVER_LICENSE).stream()
            .map(DriverFileEntity::getFile)
            .map(FileEntity::getUuid)
            .allMatch(uuid -> uuid.equals(UUID.fromString(fileId1)) || uuid.equals(UUID.fromString(fileId2)))
        );
        assertEquals(2, fileRepository.count());
        assertEquals(2, driverFileRepository.count());

        /*
         * 4) as driver, I use the driver app to check one more time the whoAmI context, this time no new upload of files is needed
         */
        MvcResult resultDriverWhoAmI2 = mockMvc.perform(
                get("/api/whoami")
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + driverToken.getValue())
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

        String whoAmI2Json = resultDriverWhoAmI2.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertThat(whoAmI2Json, hasJsonPath("$.isDriverLicenceCheckNeeded", equalTo(false))); // file(s) upload must not be done

        /*
         * 5) as distributor, I see in dashboard, that driver uploaded today 2 files and when is the next time for upload planned
         */
        MvcResult resultDriverDetails = mockMvc.perform(
                get("/api/drivers/" + DRIVER)
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + distributorToken.getValue())
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();

        String driverDetailsJson = resultDriverDetails.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertThat(driverDetailsJson, hasJsonPath("$.uuid", equalTo(DRIVER.toString()))); // file(s) upload must not be done
        assertThat(driverDetailsJson, hasJsonPath("$.firstName", equalTo("Cleo")));
        assertThat(driverDetailsJson, hasJsonPath("$.lastName", equalTo("Patra")));
        assertThat(driverDetailsJson, hasJsonPath("$.nextCheckDriverLicenceIn", equalTo(30)));
        assertThat(driverDetailsJson, hasJsonPath("$.lastCheckDriverLicence", equalTo(LocalDate.now().toString())));
        assertThat(driverDetailsJson, hasJsonPath("$.nextCheckDriverLicence", equalTo(LocalDate.now().plusDays(30).toString())));
        assertThat(driverDetailsJson, hasJsonPath("$.driverLicenceFiles.[*]", hasSize(2)));
        assertThat(driverDetailsJson, hasJsonPath("$.driverLicenceFiles.[0].uuid", equalTo(fileId1)));
        assertThat(driverDetailsJson, hasJsonPath("$.driverLicenceFiles.[1].uuid", equalTo(fileId2)));

        /*
         * 6) internal clean up, remove driver files directly in db and use cron job to remove data from file storage
         */
        // delete all driver files
        for (DriverFileEntity driverFile : driver.getDriverFiles()) driverFileRepository.deleteById(driverFile.getId());
        // driverFileRepository.flush();
        assertEquals(0, driverFileRepository.count());

        // use housekeeping cron job to remove unused files
        scheduledFileTasks.filesHouseKeeping();

        // check no more data
        assertEquals(0, fileRepository.count());
    }
}
```

I'm using zonky embeded database

pom.xml:

```java
<!-- DATABASE STUFF -->
        <org.postgresql.version>42.2.25</org.postgresql.version>
        <org.flywaydb.version>8.5.2</org.flywaydb.version>
        <com.vladmihalcea.version>2.2.2</com.vladmihalcea.version>
        <zonky.embedded-database-spring-test.version>2.1.1</zonky.embedded-database-spring-test.version>
        <io.zonky.test.version>2.0.0</io.zonky.test.version>
        <org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions.version>7.0.0</org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions.version>
        <com.amazonaws.version>1.11.163</com.amazonaws.version>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-database-spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${zonky.embedded-database-spring-test.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zonky.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedded-postgres</artifactId>
            <version>${io.zonky.test.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

zonky configuration in application.yaml:

```java
zonky:
    test:
        database:
            refresh: "before_class"
```

This is not the only test class which fails sometimes, only an example.

Tried restarting and reinstalling docker, rebuilding the project but nothing worked.

I will provide more information if needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could not determine what is the real issue in your code. But a little suggestion. Sometimes *EntityManager* also throws this kind of issue. I mean that if you have used *entityManager.close()* method the application must not invoke any further methods on the EntityManager instance except for getTransaction and isOpen. Otherwise entityManager throws this **java.lang.IllegalStateException**. Please check that part also.
[Here is a link for entityManager.close()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762974/should-jpa-entity-manager-be-closed)

Comment: I don't close the EntityManager manually. I'm using the @PersistenceContext annotation for my entityManager which closes it automatically.